What is the approx. date of the earliest manuscript containing the ending verses of 2 Corinthians 13:11-13/14?
What is the approx. date of the earliest manuscript containing the ending verses of 2 Corinthians 13:11-13/14?

11 Finally, brothers, rejoice! Aim for perfect harmony, encourage one another, be of one mind, live in peace. And the God of love and
peace will be with you.
12 Greet one another with a holy kiss.
13 All the saints send you greetings.
14 The grace of the Lord Jesus Christ, and the love of God, and the fellowship of the Holy Spirit be with all of you.


I'm curious what you will do with this information. How will knowing the date of the earliest manuscript containing a specific verse in Second Corinthians help you?

Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question and joining the group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.

Some early manuscripts containing the text of this chapter are [1]:

Papyrus 46 (~AD 200)
Codex Vaticanus (325–350)
Codex Sinaiticus (330–360)
Codex Alexandrinus (400–440)
Codex Freerianus (~450; extant verses 1–2, 10–11)
Codex Claromontanus (~550)

According to religion-online:

The oldest manuscript of the letters of Paul usually is referred to as
papyrus 46, abbreviated p46. Judging from the handwriting used in this
manuscript, it is dated around the year 200 and was produced in Egypt.
The University of Michigan in Ann Arbor acquired parts of this
manuscript, but most pages belong to the Chester Beatty collection in
Dublin, Ireland.
This manuscript is not only the oldest extant edition of the letters
of Paul but it is at the same time one of the oldest manuscripts in
book form known to exist. Up until the fourth century CE literature
was copied almost exclusively on scrolls. There is some mystery about
the origin of the codex, the Latin term for book in contrast to the
scroll. Somehow the public use of the codex is closely connected to
the formation of the New Testament. The Christians were apparently the
first ones to depart from the scroll and to use the bookform as a
medium.


Although the manuscript is in fairly good condition, the outer pages
did not survive. The text starts with Rom 5:17, then runs through
Hebrews 1 Corinthians 2 Corinthians Ephesians Galatians Philippians
Colossians and ends in 1 Thess 5:28. Because many pages still provide
their original page numbers it is easy to see that the seven missing
outer leaves holding 14 pages of text at the beginning left room for
14 corresponding pages at the end. There is no way to get the rest of
1 Thessalonians, 2 Thessalonians, 1 Timothy, 2 Timothy, Titus and
Philemon on 14 pages of the size used by p46. A fair estimate lies
somewhere close to 23 more pages necessary to hold all of the expected
text. What the scribe decided to do, we do not know.


The verse numbering varies slightly between English versions and the Greek.  Most English versions number the verses 11-14; in the Greek NT the verses are numbered 11-13 in UBS5/NA28.
The oldest known MSS containing the text of 2 Cor 13:11-13 (in the Greek) is P46 which is dated to about 200 AD.  Here is an image of the pertinent page with the last three verses (including the last four words of V10):

The text is quite legible and the text (as checked by myself) is almost identical to that in UBS5, viz:

καὶ οὐκ εἰς καθαίρεσιν. Λοιπόν, ἀδελφοί, χαίρετε, καταρτίζεσθε, παρακαλεῖσθε, τὸ αὐτὸ
φρονεῖτε, εἰρηνεύετε, καὶ ὁ Θεὸς τῆς ἀγάπης καὶ εἰρήνης ἔσται μεθ’
ὑμῶν. Ἀσπάσασθε ἀλλήλους ἐν ἁγίῳ φιλήματι. Ἀσπάζονται ὑμᾶς οἱ ἅγιοι
πάντες. Ἡ χάρις τοῦ Κυρίου Ἰησοῦ Χριστοῦ καὶ ἡ ἀγάπη τοῦ Θεοῦ καὶ ἡ
κοινωνία τοῦ Ἁγίου Πνεύματος μετὰ πάντων ὑμῶν.

Obviously, the MSS is in all capital letters (as was the custom of the time) and the modern text uses lower-case letters as well.
